# Assigning Random Values to Elements of an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays

I wrote a program that asks the user to enter two numbers M and N. There will be an array that has M*N elements that need to be assigned random values. These values are then displayed  in a M x N table. The problem is that when I run the program, The assigned value for the first element is always either 0 or some weird number like -2147197728 and the rest of the elements are always 0. Can anybody help me out?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int PopulateRandom(int M, int N);
int PrintArray2D(int M, int N);

// Prints elements of array in a M x N table
int PrintArray2D(int M, int N){
int array[M*N], row, column, i = 0;

while(row <= M && column <= N){
    for(row = 1; row <= M; row++){
        for(column = 1; column <= N; column++){
            array[i] = PopulateRandom(M, N);
            printf("%d  ", array[i]);
            if(column == 4){
                break;
            }
        }
        column = 0;
        printf("\n");
    }
}
return array[i];
}

//Assigns elements of the array "array" random values
int PopulateRandom(int M, int N){
int i, array[M * N];

for(i = 0; i < M*N; i++){
    array[i] = rand() % (M*N) - 1;
}
return array[i];
}

int main(void){
int option, M, N;

printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
scanf("%d", &option);

while(option != 0){
    switch(option){
        case 1: if(option == 1){
                printf("Enter two numbers M and N: ");                          
                scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);
                PrintArray2D(M, N);
        }
        case 0: if(option == 0){
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
    printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
    scanf("%d", &option);
}
}
```

Comment: `row` and `column` are *uninitialised variables*. Please note too that arrays in C are usually indexed from `0`. On those occasions (rarely) when it is convenient to index an array from `1` the array must 1 element larger so the upper bound is not broken.

Comment: Your `PopulateRandom` function will return a value *out of bounds* of the array. An array it doesn't really use by the way. The function could just as well contain the only statement `return rand() % (M * N) - 1;`

Comment: I initialized 'row' and 'column' in the for loops.

Comment: That was *after* `while(row <= M && column <= N)`. Please take note of compiler warnings.

Comment: The `PrintArray2D` function doesn't need an array either, all you use in that function is `array[0]`.

Comment: Once you get past your initialization and array bounds issues, you should also seed the `rand` function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693511/rand-seeding-with-time-problem

Comment: Any reason you don't use a 2D array? And don't pass the array to the functions?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a value held at an index outside of your array here

```
   int PopulateRandom(int M, int N){
       int i, array[M * N];

       for(i = 0; i < M*N; i++){
           array[i] = rand() % (M*N) - 1;
       }
       return array[i];
   }
```

i will be equal to M * N when the loop ends, array[i] will be outside of array since the size of array is M*N.